# Database schema practical approach

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I want to model 2 entities in database: `CafeBrand` and `Cafe`. I have pretty much the same properties in both entities:

```
CafeBrand{
 foodDescription,
 website,
 email,
 phone
}

cafe{
 foodDescription,
 website,
 email,
 phone
}
```

So let's say in case of McDonalds all 'cafes' would have the same foodDescription: 'Junk food'. But some other brands might have separate food description for separate cafes('sandwiches', 'drinks only', ...).

Same with website/email/phone properties: cafe might have its own website/email/phone but also it could be using the same website/email/phone for all of them. Quite often the same CafeBrand has one website but different email/phone for its different cafes.

**My question is:** is it wise to store these properties as it is and then use if/else (in SQL or code) to get a proper description,website,email,phone (if cafe.website == null then use cafebrand.website) or is it better to use relationships to separate tables 'FoodDescription', 'Website' The data won't be written to the database very often and most of the time only select statements will be used.

And if Company has a single cafe. How should this foodDescription/Website be split into CafeBrand/Cafe tables.

Comment: The fact that you have 2 tables with nearly identical columns should be a huge red flag that you have modeled something wrong.  If they are the same, put them in the same table with another column that differentiates them from one another.  One table called "Stores" or "Restaraunts".  Then have a flag or indicator of "Cafe" or "CafeBrand".

Comment: So to store all McDonals restaurants in some area I would have to insert 'Junk food' as the 'brand' record and then reference this record in other restaurants and use 'if/else' in all my queries to get correct website/food/phone/email. Is that correct?

Comment: It's SQL.  You don't "if/else".  You "WHERE RestaurantBrand = 'McDonalds'"

Comment: I'm using 'if/else' in general not as keywords of sql. So I have 10 McD cafes and 1 brand with (foodDescription/website/..). With this approach, whenever I needed to get a cafe info (with website/phone/email) I would have to join cafe(exact)  with cafe (brand) and use ISNULL(exact.website, brand.website) for every field. Anyways, thanks for suggestion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Bill Gregg has mentioned you should probably put all similar data in one table. So you'll receive following structure:

```
cafe {
   foodDescription,
   website,
   email,
   phone,
   brand
}
```

Because of `foodDescription`, `website` and so on columns will contains pretty unique values I assume, you won't gain any profit with separation the data into different tables.

Comment: So to store all McDonals restaurants in some area I would have to insert 'Junk food' as the 'brand' record and then reference this record in other restaurants and use 'if/else' in all my queries to get correct website/food/phone/email. Is that correct?

Comment: Yes.This way you'll receive some kind of properties override.

Comment: Also you can use `COALESCE` function instead of if/else in your SQL